# Run custom cron on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cron

Just working on a custom wordpress plugin. It will have an export and import function that need to be run at very exact times. So for those 2 functions I am ditching the wp-cron and set up cron jobs via crontab.

But how do I run only those 2 functions in this plugin but nothing else?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Would it be save to simply schedule a cron that would load an ajax url and would trigger the import or export depending on the action?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but this ideas might work.
You can create custom php file at root of wordpress installation and add

```
 <?php
 define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
 require("wp-load.php");
```

Now you can use all wordpress and plugin functions. Then you can set this file to execute by your webhost cron.

Other than that in functions.php of your theme whatever is outside function will be always executed. so you can set some GET parameter and check in functions.php for that parameter in url and execute a function. You need to set that parameter in cron job url at your webhost cpanle.

Comment: because it is a plugin generating a php file in the wordpress root directory is not really the way forward as all files should be within the plugins folder.

I got it working with the ajax url. Is that a safe way to do it?

Comment: I don't think it will create any trouble with your security.

Comment: Please post how you did here so other can get benefit of it.

Comment: In my plugin I have this line 

add_action( 'wp_ajax_export_data', array($this, 'export');

Then I have a a function called export();

All you need to do then is schedule a cron for this url

http://YOURDOMAIN.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=export_data 

and boom. done.